# using d3.js, how to append <textpath> to some already existing <paths> of svg?

Tags: d3.js

Initial html is as follows

```html
<svg>
<g id="groupOfPaths">
<path id="foo_1" d="M 80,40 Q 200,85 245,205" stroke="red" stroke-width="2"/>     
<path id="foo_2" d="M 150,40 Q 200,85 245,205" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" />
</g></svg>
```

using d3 how can i append textpath to all the existing path tags such that output is as follows

```html
    <svg>
<g id="groupOfPaths">
<path id="foo_1" d="M 80,40 Q 200,85 245,205" stroke="red" stroke-width="2"/>     
<path id="foo_2" d="M 150,40 Q 200,85 245,205" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" />

<!--extra added tags-->
<text fill="red">
    <textPath xlink:href="foo_1">1 path text follow</textPath>
</text>
<text fill="red">
        <textPath xlink:href="foo_2">101 path text follow</textPath>
</text>


</g></svg>
```

**Edited the question to incorportate Id for each path**

Comment: Select the `g` element and then append `d3.select("#groupOfPaths").append("text").append("textPath")`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff:but how to get the exact ids as of the paths for "xlink:href"

Comment: Also how to write two <textpaths> as there are 2 <paths>.

Comment: First, you need to set the ID as `<path id="foo1">` (names cannot start with a number). You can get the IDs like this `var ids = []; d3.select("#groupOfPaths").selectAll("path").each(function() { ids.push(this.id); });` and then you can use `ids` as data for a selection of `text` elements.